# What are the various ways that hybrid rocket engines are "turned on" or ignited?

Tags: engine-design, hybrid-rocket, ignition

I want to know the more complex side of hybrid rocket engines. I already know most of the basics like Newtons third law and oxidizer.

But I want to learn more of the complex stuff. I know they are "turned on" (ignited) by putting some sort of "fire" and then the engine starts, but what are the details of that process, and what different ways are there to start it?

---

Wikipedia's [Hybrid-propellant rocket; Basic concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-propellant_rocket#Basic_concepts) says the following, but "a suitable ignition source" is vague:

> In its simplest form, a hybrid rocket consists of a pressure vessel (tank) containing the liquid oxidiser, the combustion chamber containing the solid propellant, and a mechanical device separating the two. When thrust is desired, **a suitable ignition source** is introduced in the combustion chamber and the valve is opened. The liquid oxidiser (or gas) flows into the combustion chamber where it is vaporized and then reacted with the solid propellant. Combustion occurs in a boundary layer diffusion flame adjacent to the surface of the solid propellant.

[image: Hybrid engine example]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hybrids_big-tosvg.svg)

Comment: I had a professor once tell me that the "closest kept secret about an engine is how to light it."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-propellant_rocket This Wikipedia page explains them pretty well.

Comment: But it doesnt explain how does the lighting of the engine work. Or i dint understand.

Comment: Hi @supergmaer welcome to Space SE! I've added that link back into your question and narrowed the scope of your question down to only the part about ignition. I think that there will be a variety of ignition mechanisms for different combinations of propellant chemicals, so the answers will be pretty interesting!

Comment: An igniter requiring a liquid fuel does not make sense for a hybrid rocket. So only a solid igniter may be used. This could be something like a small solid fuel rocket producing hot particles and/or hot gases that will ignite the hybrid fuel. You need a point where the liquid oxidizer, the hybrid fuel and the hot exhaust from the igniter gets a close contact.  A turbulent flow of the oxidizer would help to mix the components at the ignition point. Only if there is a hypergolic liquid oxidizer for the hybrid fuel, a liquid igniter may be used. Ignition is done then only by contact.

Comment: To amplify on the answer by Uwe, igniters in solids and many hybrids are themselves miniature solid rocket motors. They are designed to produce quite hot, reactive gases in some cases (not same propellants as in normal solid motors), and easy to start electrically. From the one AIAA course I took on hybrids in 2011 (so I'm no expert), the biggest problem with ignition is keeping the liquid flow from extinguishing the initial flame front started by the igniter. Controlled liquid introduction is required. YMMV with more modern materials and methods.